# Adding axes and axis number to grid system in three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, axis-labels, axes

I'd like to know how to draw axes and add axis labels and numbers to grid system in three.js, like this one below (I have already created the grid system with GridHelper):

Example can be found here: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/contourf3d_demo2.hires.png

What I have done so far can be found here: [surface-plot-3d](http://jesusjzp.github.io/projects/surface3d/index.html)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Excuse me I don't have the right to post image yet, so I added the link to the current project. @RickSmith

Comment: google 'makeTextSprite'. This is the function used for what you are looking, copied [from Stemkoski's](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html). Also related : [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30735527/three-js-maketextsprite-properties), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171238/trying-to-make-text-sprites-clickable-in-three-js), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591858/three-js-how-to-make-my-text-sprite-clearer), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514274/three-js-2d-text-sprite-labels).

Comment: Thanks @Atrahasis! I'm a newbee to three.js, I thought there was an API or something for labeling. Ok, I'm going to add text manually, thanks for your advice!